How do you determine the critical region/decision rule in hypothesis testing?
I'm currently studying hypothesis testing for one sample t-tests. In a PowerPoint presentation uploaded by my professor, it was stated that the critical region/decision rule for ${H}_{a}$: μ ≠ ${μ}_{0}$ should be "Reject the null hypothesis if ${t}_{computed}$ > ${t}_{a/2, (n-1)}$".
However, for the same alt. hypothesis ${H}_{a}$: μ ≠ ${μ}_{0}$, she has also used the decision rule "Reject the null hypothesis if p-value < α (0.05)". Similarly, this was an example involving one sample t-tests.
Given that they are of the same type of test, I don't understand how they could have different decision rules. What do I look at and how do I determine which one to use?

The critical value $t_{\alpha/2, n-1}$ depends on the significance level $\alpha$, so the decision rules are equivalent, just measured in different ways.
To illustrate, suppose the sample size is $n = 17$ and the desired significance level is $\alpha = 0.05$.  Then the critical value for the two-sided test is $$t_{0.025, 16} \approx 2.11991,$$ which is the $97.5^{\rm th}$ percentile of the Student $t$-distribution with $n-1 = 16$ degrees of freedom.  If the test statistic has absolute value exceeding this number, then your decision rule tells you to reject the null hypothesis.
How would you calculate the $p$-value?  It is the twice the probability that a Student $t$-distributed random variable with $n-1$ degrees of freedom exceeds the absolute value of the observed test statistic; i.e., $$p = \Pr[t_{16} > |T|],$$ where $$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}},$$ and $\bar X$ is the sample mean, $\mu_0$ is the null mean, and $s$ is the sample standard deviation.  But when $T = t_{0.025,16}$, this probability equals $\alpha$ by construction, because the $100(1-\alpha/2)$ percentile of the Student $t$ distribution equals the value for which the probability of being larger equals $\alpha/2$; then multiplying by $2$ gives us $\alpha$.
Let's look at a numerical example.  Again, our sample size is $n = 17$ and suppose the data are
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
3.37175 & -1.62342 & -0.0573507 & 1.24424 & 4.10355 \\
0.277026 & 1.91402 & -0.816693 & 3.81101 & 5.98978 \\
3.23871 & -1.48083 & 1.11471 & 0.751903 & 2.64585 \\
-0.694847 & -0.284174 &&&
\end{array}$$
The sample mean is $\bar X \approx 1.38266$ and the sample variance is $s^2 \approx 4.79735$.  If we are interested in testing the hypothesis
$$H_0 : \mu = \mu_0 = 0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \mu \ne 0,$$
then the test statistic
$$T \mid H_0 = \frac{\bar X - 0}{\sqrt{s^2/n}} \sim t_{n-1}$$
is Student $t$-distributed with $16$ degrees of freedom.  We calculate
$T \approx 2.60279$, which exceeds $t_{0.025,16} \approx 2.11991$, so this leads us to reject $H_0$ at the $\alpha = 0.05$ significance level and we conclude the data furnishes sufficient evidence that the mean is not zero.
Now if we calculate the $p$-value, it is
$$2 \Pr[t_{16} > 2.60279] \approx 2(0.00961574) = 0.0192315.$$
This is less than $\alpha$, so again, we reject $H_0$.
Had the test statistic been exactly $2.11991$, then $$2 \Pr[t_{16} > 2.11991] = 2(0.025) = 0.05.$$

If it is known that the top $(100-97)\%$ of students can get a score at least $90$ in a particular test, then one's score is $\geq90$ is equivalent to the percentile of the student is higher than $97\%$.

Comparing actual score with the bar $90$ is like comparing observed $t$ value with the cutoff $t_{{\alpha/2},\nu}$.
Comparing observed percentile with $97\%$ is like comparing observed $p$ value with the prechosen $\alpha$.

